# Running nosetests using pypy

Tags: python, nose, pypy

[PyPy is compatible with nose](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/nose), so how can I use that? I already use:

```
nosetests-2.7 ; nosetests3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside nosetests script (on my PC: `/usr/local/bin/nosetests`) it turns out it's a python script with a header like `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Therefore, to make sure you run nosetests with a particular interpreter, run:

- `python /usr/local/bin/nosetests`
- `pypy /usr/local/bin/nosetests`